# ffmpeg fails with: Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to record my desktop and save it as videos but ffmpeg fails.

Here is the terminal output:

```
$ ffmpeg -f alsa -i pulse -r 30 -s 1366x768 -f x11grab -i :0.0 -vcodec libx264 - preset ultrafast -crf 0 -y screencast.mp4
...
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
```

Comment: add ```-f mp4``` just before filename and move ```-r 30 -s 1366x768``` before -vcodec

Comment: @Ulterior That will result in x11grab using default settings (`-r 25 -s 648x480`), so your suggestion of changing these options from input options to output options will cause frame duplication (25 to 30) and upscaling (640x480 to 1366x768). `-f mp4` is superfluous in this case.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## typo

Use `-preset`, not `- preset` (notice the space). `ffmpeg` uses `-` to indicate a pipe, so your typo is being interpreted as a piped output.

## pipe requires the `-f` option

For users who get the same error, but actually want to output via a pipe, you have to tell `ffmpeg` which muxer the pipe should use.

Do this with the `-f` output option. Examples: `-f mpegts`, `-f nut`, `-f wav`, `-f matroska`. Which one to use depends on your video/audio formats and your particular use case.

You can see a list of muxers with `ffmpeg -muxers` (not all muxers can be used with pipe).

Comment: Just to point out, the order of options is important too. E.g. your `-f mp3` should come after the `-i` parameter.